# Vscode in WSL2 (Ubuntu): Cant update extensions, terminal / shell not working

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

Since some of the latest vscode updates i am not able to use the terminal, nor can i update any extension updates.

The only solution to the extension update problem i've found is switching to another DNS server, I've tried this (8.8.8.8) but nothing changed (https://gist.github.com/coltenkrauter/608cfe02319ce60facd76373249b8ca6).

The console looks like this:

[image]

I am unable to type anything inside the terminal.

Starting Vscode without extensions also doesn't bring the console to life.

Updated Ubuntu and Windows 10. Same problem on two Windows 10 PCs, while the second ones WSL distro is imported from the first.

Any ideas how to solve this?

==========================

**Update:** Disabling terminal.integrated.inheritEnv brings the console back. But this seems more like a workaround than a solution.

**Update 2:** Switching to the Vscode insider preview also "fixed" the extension update problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly what solved this issue, after a **Docker for Windows update** it started working again. But this may just a coincidence, possibly a VSCODE update came the same day.

I've switched back to VSCODE stable, everything works perfectly fine so far.

So, ensure you have:

- Windows
- VSCODE
- Your Linux WSL Distro
- Docker for Windows

up to date.

If it's still not working, try to switch to VSCODE insider (you can install this next to the stable version).